# Iterator Variable Naming Convention in .NET

Tags: .net

In a standard foreach loop, is there a generally accepted naming convention for the iterator variable?

Typically, I use currXXX where XXX is basically the name of what I'm iterating through. I haven't seen others follow this convention, it's just something I've been doing as long as I can remember. I do see value in having a name similar to what I'm iterating.

Any opinions? Any "official" recommendations?

```
foreach(var currName in names)
{
   //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no official recommendations that I'm aware of, but I tend to use the `foreach (var singular in plural)` pattern. For example:

```
foreach (var name in names)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I agree. I always use singular/plural

Comment: The same pattern here. Seems natural.

Comment: Guess it was just my own bad habit, glad I asked!

Answer (score 2):

Use the plural and singulare like the others say, and avoid 'curr'.

If you must use it, use 'current'. Abreviated prefixes like curr, but also like s (for strings), i (for integers), and other abreviations only make code less readable. The only added value is less typing and less diskspace (which isn't added value in these days). But before you know it, people are using stuff like dpdl for dropdownlist, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, when possible just use this form:

```
foreach (var single in plural)
```

However, sometimes that won't make sense or you won't be able to do it (perhaps the name is already spoken for).  In that case:

```
foreach (var item in plural)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing official, as far as I know. I usually use plural for the collection, and the singular form for the single entity:

```
foreach(string name in names) {}
foreach(Car car in cars) {}
foreach(User user in users) {}
```

you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

I would not var in this case because it not clear what type currName is.

I would explicitly specify the type:

```
foreach(YourType currName in names)
{
   //do stuff
}
```